# How to open/connect to mysql .mad files (temporary tables)

Tags: mysql, temporary

We've had a bad problem of full disk with our mysql servers. It took about 2 minutes to fill up our disk of very large .mad files in the tmp folder. We did some research, it seems they are temporary table files.

Here's an example of those filename : #sql_e802_0 (doesn't seem to have an extension but in the properties it says "MAD" (881 MB). It's accompanied by another file #sql_e802_0.MAI (32KB).

There where a large number of those files all of exactly the same size so we guess it was an infinite loop or something.

We need to know what the files countain to know which of our service is the cause.

Is there anyway to open these files or connect to it or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think MariaDB databases (.mad) cannot be just 'opened,' but rather must be connected to, using the cross-platform MariaDB engine. and check the below link too.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255117/disk-full-of-mysql-mad-and-mai-files

Comment: In this post, I don't see any reference to how to connect to a Mad file using the cross-platform MariaDB engine.